# How can OAuth authentication save data when logging in with Google?

Tags: mongodb, next.js, oauth-2.0, next.js13

hi I'm learning NextJS and OAuth authentication but I have a question as to how to save user data when logging in with google so that when registering, the email previously logged in with google is not registered anymore.

Another thing is when I want to code a blog website and get mongodb as the backend, when a certain user writes an article, how can I get the exact article that user wrote.
hi I'm learning NextJS and OAuth authentication but I have a question as to how to save user data when logging in with google so that when registering, the email previously logged in with google is not registered anymore.

Another thing is when I want to code a blog website and get mongodb as the backend, when a certain user writes an article, how can I get the exact article that user wrote.